# Signing DKIM error with UTF8 character in body

Tags: .net, dkim

I'm trying to sign DKIM for my email message.

With the non-unicode body, it work well :

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_000_0011_01CF8271.717F57C0
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="windows-1258"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is a test email from UltraMailer.

------=_NextPart_000_0011_01CF8271.717F57C0
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

This is a test email from UltraMailer.
------=_NextPart_000_0011_01CF8271.717F57C0--
```

But if the content contain utf-8 character, i received message from Gmail indicate that my bodyhash (bh) have wrong: dkim=neutral (body hash did not verify)

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_000_0020_01CF8275.DAAA6BA0
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="windows-1258"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

tieng viet




------=_NextPart_000_0020_01CF8275.DAAA6BA0
Content-Type: text/html;
    charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

tiáº¿ng viá»‡t 
<P>&nbsp;</P>
------=_NextPart_000_0020_01CF8275.DAAA6BA0--
```

My DKIM header :

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain.info; s=default; t=1402142861; bh=KjwC9TmOTS+OUAQOHQ9T6mW1PbMSe3HZ5uaN2ZDGcEQ=; h=From:To:Subject; b=DgZIGVaYd+tZ1VE7z1X2V7znolfmUp+ejSmsNmwYxIPlckH+AwrXyaetwbVGnkY9ybiUEcKXEhY6HRMMRIFZIb2QwbAhGNppN+lcvOBLVaghrVQ6Emg7dP1+VkzaJ1+qqROIg6pO+U/oAnFx4HH8mDGNvDxDlePrq5hSXvRKQ/c=
```

What wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit`:
If you use special characters, Thunderbird switches the content transfer encoding automatically to 8bit.

This can cause problems with different DKIM signing applications.

See: https://github.com/Pro/dkim-exchange/issues/86
or http://sourceforge.net/p/dkimproxy/mailman/message/188564/

So the solution would be to force thunderbird to not use 8bit encoding. This can be achieved by setting `mail.strictly_mime` to true. (See: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=1697835)